# Exif data returns string with ? box characters only within javascript

Tags: php, javascript, exif

I'm fetching exif data using `exif_read_data` and inserting it into an image alt tag which works fine, but when I fetch that data using javascript `(var hovertext = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');)` a bunch of weird question mark/box characters appear in the output..  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you've got some problems with your charset. Which charset is used on your website and in the EXIF-data?

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
    ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');
```

edit: if you  haven't set the encoding for your html, then

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

edit2:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('picname.jpg', 0, true);
echo "picname.jpg:<br />\n";
        foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Please run this on any picture and provide result for "COMPUTED.UserCommentEncoding:"

Comment: please provide the value for any of the attributes in question.

Comment: S�e�v�e�n� �D�e�a�d�l�y� �S�i�n�s���

Comment: is this copied from the html or is this the return value of jquery find method?

Comment: It appears when I 'inspect element' but not when I echo the string.. Only when it's appended in javascript

Comment: 'COMPUTED.UserCommentEncoding' doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: well.. what you could do is str_replace() � with an "" empty string.